# No visible @interface for 'AFHTTPSessionManager' declares the selector 'dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

Just now I'm updated AFNetworkig into 4.0. I got this error. How to resolve this error?
This is my code

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =  [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/xml"];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSDictionary *responses = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:responseObject error:nil];
        BOLog(@"responsess%@",responses);
        block(responses,nil);

    }];
    [task resume];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSDictionary *responses = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:responseObject error:nil];
        BOLog(@"responsess%@",responses);
        block(responses,nil);
    }];
    [task resume];
```

Comment: Hi @iOS, Is the above change working fine for you?